# Recursion to return check both array[i+1] and array[i-1]

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm making a timeline, and want to layer 'activities' based on how many overlaps occur.

I've found several answers on stack overflow on how to count overlapping intervals, though in my case I want the count to increase when an the overlap is indirect.

I've come up with the following recursive method:

```
countOverlaps: function(i, allItems) {

    var currentItem = allItems[i];

    // Declare position variables
    var currentItemStart = this.getStartTimeMinutes(currentItem.timeStartString);
    var currentItemEnd = currentItemStart + currentItem.duration;

    var nextItemStart = (i < allItems.length - 1) ? this.getStartTimeMinutes(allItems[i + 1].timeStartString) : null;
    var nextItemEnd = (nextItemStart != null) ? nextItemStart + allItems[i + 1].duration : null;

    var prevItemStart = (i >= 1) ? this.getStartTimeMinutes(allItems[i - 1].timeStartString) : null;
    var prevItemEnd = (prevItemStart != null) ? prevItemStart + allItems[i - 1].duration : null;

    // The logic
    // If the next item is an overlap, test the next item

    // If the previous item is an overlap, test the previous item

    if (currentItemEnd > nextItemStart && currentItemStart < nextItemEnd && nextItemStart != null) {
        return 1 + this.countOverlaps((i + 1), allItems); // BUT how do I do the same for the previous one?
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

},
```

But now I'm stuck. I think it's working how I want, except that it's only counting forward. If I want to check backwards and forward, will each recursive call not test the same index again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all recursions you do something with only ONE element/ item in the function. Remember the terminiation - this is the most important thing in a recursion (no it is not the self call, because without it it won't be a recursion at all).
After that you will call yourself with another modified parameter.

Since I understand you correctly you want to start somewhere and go to left and right as far you want. Look at the terminiation code. You should change the condition to your needs.

The start `sum left and sum right` is not part of the recursion, because you only want to go in one direction per recursion.

This code is simple so you can easly adapt it to you need.

```
function sum(index, array){    
    function sumRecursion(index, array, direction){
        // the termination ;)
        if (index < 0) return 0;
        if (index > array.length) return 0;

        // do some stuff with your array at the current index.
        // sorry, I did'nt read your logic code
        var count = ...

        // now the recursion
        return count + sum(index + direction, array, direction);
    }
    return sumRecursion(index, array, -1) + sumRecursion(index, array, +1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, just looking at the code; when the sum function is called, the return of the sumRecursion function + the return of the sumRecursion function will be returned? Think I got it :)

Comment: I'm struggling with the 'this' binding now though... when I call 'this' from within the sumRecursion function I'm getting the call site as from the window option as opposed to from the call site where I originally called sum() from.

Comment: Why do you need a "this" context. Call the sum(index, array, elementOrWhatEver) and then you do not need this anymore.
I can not determine what "this" is for you. I need more information about the first call.